# AccessAbiltyService not working when screen turn off android

Tags: java, android

I develop a android app here hava a accessabilty service for read window text from ussd dial.
I am success for do it and it working nice.  But when screen light turn off and get locked The accessAbiltyService not working.
I provide my coding here of access ability service

please see and give me suggestion  how I solve it that it working for screen on/off.

```
public class USSDService extends AccessibilityService {

public static String TAG = USSDService.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {


    AccessibilityNodeInfo source = event.getSource();
    /* if (event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED && !event.getClassName().equals("android.app.AlertDialog")) { // android.app.AlertDialog is the standard but not for all phones  */
    if (event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED && !String.valueOf(event.getClassName()).contains("AlertDialog")) {
        return;
    }
    if(event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_CONTENT_CHANGED && (source == null || !source.getClassName().equals("android.widget.TextView"))) {
        return;
    }
    if(event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_CONTENT_CHANGED && TextUtils.isEmpty(source.getText())) {
        return;
    }

    List<CharSequence> eventText;

    if(event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED) {
        eventText = event.getText();
    } else {
        eventText = Collections.singletonList(source.getText());
    }

    String text = processUSSDText(eventText);

    if( TextUtils.isEmpty(text) ) return;

    // Close dialog
    performGlobalAction(GLOBAL_ACTION_BACK); // This works on 4.1+ only

    if (source != null) {
        //capture the EditText simply by using FOCUS_INPUT (since the EditText has the focus), you can probably find it with the viewId input_field
        AccessibilityNodeInfo inputNode = source.findFocus(AccessibilityNodeInfo.FOCUS_INPUT);
        if (inputNode != null) {//prepare you text then fill it using ACTION_SET_TEXT



        //saff 1
            if (text.indexOf("Default") >= 0) {
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
            arguments.putCharSequence(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_ARGUMENT_SET_TEXT_CHARSEQUENCE,"0");
            inputNode.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_SET_TEXT, arguments);

        //"Click" the Send button
        List<AccessibilityNodeInfo> list = source.findAccessibilityNodeInfosByText("Send");
        for (AccessibilityNodeInfo node : list) {
            node.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK);
        }
    }





    //staf 2


            if (text.indexOf("topUp") >= 0) {
                Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
                arguments.putCharSequence(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_ARGUMENT_SET_TEXT_CHARSEQUENCE,"1");
                inputNode.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_SET_TEXT, arguments);

                //"Click" the Send button
                List<AccessibilityNodeInfo> list = source.findAccessibilityNodeInfosByText("Send");
                for (AccessibilityNodeInfo node : list) {
                    node.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK);
                }
            }





        }

        }
    Log.d(TAG, text);
    // Handle USSD response here

}

private String processUSSDText(List<CharSequence> eventText) {
    for (CharSequence s : eventText) {
        String text = String.valueOf(s);
        // Return text if text is the expected ussd response
        if( true ) {
            return text;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onInterrupt() {
}

@Override
protected void onServiceConnected() {
    super.onServiceConnected();
    Log.d(TAG, "onServiceConnected");
    AccessibilityServiceInfo info = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();
    info.flags = AccessibilityServiceInfo.DEFAULT;
    info.packageNames = new String[]{"com.android.phone"};
    info.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED | AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_CONTENT_CHANGED;
    info.feedbackType = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_GENERIC;
    setServiceInfo(info);
}
}
```

Thanks
For help

Comment: Hey @Osman Gani did u get any solution for this?